# Would it be wise to use pointers to return array and ni_;

Tags: c

```
int intrprice(int size, float array[], float max, int  ni_, float int_[]);
{
 /* Finding Interesting Values */
int i;

ni_=0;
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  if (array[i] > max / 2)
      {int_[ni_++] = array[i];}

return(ni_);
}
```

How can I integrate pointers in this function?

Comment: If you are going to overwrite a passed argument to `0` then don't pass it - use local variable instead.

Comment: what you want to return in this function?

Comment: ni_ and the array

Comment: You don't need to return `int_`, because changes to the array `int_[]` are visible from the calling function. BTW, pointers are already integrated, since `float int_[]` is adjusted to `float *int_` in the function parameter list.

Comment: oh yeah you re right,i got it finally.cheers